# Discord Bot use slash command

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

i want to let a bot use slash commands of another bot. If i send a message like /help it will not use the Slash function, instead it will just send "/help" (is not using the Slash Command function).
Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Did you invite your bot with `slash.command` in your `url`?

Comment: So let me make sure I understand this correctly, you want to send a message that bot1 will reply to with the command that triggers bot2 to use a command. For example https://pastebin.com/c83Y0SEL If so then yes it is possible

Comment: @Gh0st Lets assume i invite the Mee2 Bot on my server and i want to let my bot use the /help command of the Mee2 Bot. The same way as any User would type /help the bot would type /help and trigger the /help command of the Mee2 Bot.

Comment: The wording of this question is a bit confusing. Are you trying to run the *message command* (i.e. using sent messages) of another bot, or the *slash command* (i.e. using interactions) of another bot? There is a massive difference. Bots cannot execute slash commands, period, because only a human can trigger interactions. Bots can send messages, so they can execute message commands; however, any decent bot will prevent other bots from running its commands (for numerous reasons).

Comment: @Cannicide Are you certain that bots cannot trigger interactions, or is this just an assumption you made because no library/API to do so is known to you? There is a difference between "they can't" and "I don't think they can."

Comment: @Kröw Yes, I am certain. The Discord API does not allow interactions to be triggered by bots. You can check their API documentation and see for yourself. Creating interactions is client-side only, i.e. only a human user account can trigger them, as I mentioned previously. Because the official Discord API does not support this, there is no other API or library that can support it either. You could potentially use a user selfbot to do this, but that is against Discord's ToS, and I doubt that is what the OP would've wanted to do anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Bots cannot use other bot's slash commands, as they're not able to send [Application Command Interactions](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands), only receive them.

If the other bot still uses regular message-prefix commands (like `!help`), you can try sending a message with the command, but most bots ignore commands from other bots as [it is a best practice to do so](https://github.com/meew0/discord-bot-best-practices).

If the bot on the other end is developed by you, you can program it to allow message commands from your first bot, but be very careful not to create infinite loops.

Comment: it's literally in the bot oauth permissions list "application.command" if you want a bot to be allowed to do this, you can do it

Comment: @ErikAronesty As per [the discord developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/tutorials/upgrading-to-application-commands#registering-commands), `application.command` allows bots to register and display commands in that guild, not use other bots' commands.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my comment is what you were looking for this should solve your query.

```js
// Bot 1
const {
    Client
} = require("discord.js")

const client = new Client({
    intents: '...'
})
const prefix = '/'

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) && !message.author.bot) {
        const command = `/${message.content}`
        const response = message.reply(`${message.author}, relaying command`)

        await response.then(message.channel.send(command))
    }
})
```

```js
// Bot 2
const {
    Client
} = require("discord.js")

const client = new Client({
    intents: '...'
})
const bot_1_id = '4654564984981981894654'
const prefix = '/'

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot && message.author.id === bot_1_id && message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/)
        const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase()
        const command = client.commands.get(cmd)

        // if you don't have command files

        if (cmd === 'help') {
            message.channel.send(`${message.author} I recognized your help command`)
            return
        }
        // if you have a command files see below script for file

        if (!command) return
        
        try {
            command.execute(message, args)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            message.reply(`Couldn't run command`)
        }
    } else {
        return
    }
})
```

Optional if you want to/do use command files

```js
// Command File
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'help command',
    async execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} I recognized your help command`)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Am i right, that i need permission to the first bot?  If so, is there anyway without the needs of having permission?

Comment: So yes and no. If the other bot is set up to ignore other bots, which most are then this won’t work. However if they aren’t then it will.