# Send command to discord bot with python

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have written a simple code which sends a post request with a token and a message.

However, when I send a command as a message, it is not recognized by the bot, but is simply seen as a normal message.

Command:
**/generate description:world**

The bot does not respond to the message. How can I send the message using Python so that the bot sees it as a command and executes it?

Code:

```
import requests


def send_discord_message():
    url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1095975130758393868/messages"
    payload = {
        'content':"/generate description:world"
    }
    header = {
        'authorization': 'token'
    }
    requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=header)
    
send_discord_message()
```

I have already tried different messages, but none of them worked.
However, when I enter the command alone in Discord, it is recognized and the command is executed by the bot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot use slash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821385/discord-bot-use-slash-command)