# How to send message as slash command in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a bot (Let's name it `A`) already connected to the channel, and it has a slash command '/greet' that takes a `prompt` and acts upon it. Now I am trying to write a bot `B` here, that sends a command `/greet prompt hello!` for example, which will trigger the bot `A`, and `A` will provide the appropriate output to the prompt.

The problem is, when I run my script below, it doesn't understand that it's supposed to be a slash command, and send to discord as a raw string. How to fix this?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 

discord_token = '' 
channel_id = ""
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=discord.Intents.all()) 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot connected")
    await client.get_channel(int(channel_id)).send('/greet prompt hello')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    print('We are successfully triggering the bot')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.run(discord_token)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Discord's developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/tutorials/upgrading-to-application-commands#registering-commands) Bots cannot use other bot's slash commands, as they're not able to send [Application Command Interactions](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands), only receive them.

If the other bot also uses regular message-prefix - or hybrid - commands (like !greet), you could make it work.

If the bot on the other end is developed by you, you can program it to allow message commands from your first bot, but be aware that it is not a best practice to do so. Be very careful not to create infinite loops.

Source reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74494667/19676197

Answer (score -1):

The basic answer is that bots can't use slash commands. But with on_message events you can do some things:

```py
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
        if message.author.id == YOUR_BOT_ID and message.content == "Hello!":
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            await message.channel.send(f"Hello {message.author.mention}!")
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

You can change the response and what the message content should equal.