# How to use the commands of other bots in discord with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXCwK.png)
How to use commands like that with discord.py?
i have code that write the same but it is not working.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import asyncio



intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

discord_bot_token = ''
discord_bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

aiogram_bot_token = ''
aiogram_bot = Bot(token=aiogram_bot_token)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(aiogram_bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Привет из aiogram-бота!")


    discord_channel_id = 
    discord_channel = discord_bot.get_channel(discord_channel_id)

    if discord_channel:
        await discord_channel.send("/imagine cat")


async def run_discord_bot():
    await discord_bot.start(discord_bot_token)

async def run_aiogram_bot():
    await dp.skip_updates()
    await dp.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [run_discord_bot(), run_aiogram_bot()]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW5wt.png)
pls help

Maybe i need to interact with midjourney from user profile?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Discord's developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/tutorials/upgrading-to-application-commands#registering-commands) Bots cannot use other bot's slash commands, as they're not able to send [Application Command Interactions](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands), only receive them.

If the other bot also uses regular message-prefix - or hybrid - commands (like !imagine cat), you could make it work.

Source reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74494667/19676197

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply

## You can't

Discord bots simply CANNOT use slash commands of other bots

Comment: Your answer is correct, but maybe provide background information to support it?